# Is there anyway to have Notepad++ highlight both PHP and HTML at the same time?

Tags: php, html, syntax, notepad++

I've used Notepad++ for PHP editing with HTML tags echoed out.  Notepad++ had always highlighted, and interacted with the HTML, CSS, Javascript, and PHP code all in the same document.

The latest versions seem to only highlight PHP code only, and all the rest of the code be it HTML, CSS, Javscript just gets greyed out, and bunched together.

Here's the screenshot of how the html and javascript look. Switching the language from the menu bar to PHP, HTML, or Javascript doesn't change anything though.

[image]

Is there any way to enable this feature again?

Comment: Notepad++ 5.9.0 still highlights HTML, JavaScript and PHP (but not CSS) all in a single document for me. You may want to check your filetype/language associations and see if Notepad++ is treating the right file extensions the right way.

Comment: But what do you mean by "bunched together"? A screenshot would be helpful.

Comment: You should take your problem to the developers of Notepad++http://notepad-plus-plus.org/

Comment: @BoltClock: PHP files are associated to NPP.  Your right, "bunched together" doesn't mean any sense.  I mean that it's just greyed out.  I'll attach a screenshot

Comment: Here's the screenshot of how the html and javascript look.  Switching the language from the menu bar to PHP, HTML, or Javascript doesn't change anything though.

Comment: http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/823/npph.jpg/

Answer (score 4):

Looking at the screenshot, it seems your markup is all in a string that's being echoed out. In that case, Notepad++ is acting normally, highlighting the entire string as a PHP string.

Remember that you don't need to use `echo` to print HTML. You can embed PHP in HTML (or HTML in PHP) by using PHP's opening and closing delimiters to break out and back in to PHP code anywhere in your files (see the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phpmode.php)). If you close your PHP code with `?>` rather than use `echo "`, and open it back up at the end of the string with `<?php` instead of `";`, your HTML should highlight as HTML again.

Comment: This is an excerpt of a project that I'm working on, and it just outputs HTML for forms, tables, and collects JavaScript variables. NPP used to recognize and see through these all though. It looked so nice and clean, lol.

Comment: @chris: I don't remember it happening. If it did, it was probably a bug :/

Answer (score 2):

*Thankfully*, no.

I ran into this 'problem' too. Then after an hour of trying to enable this 'feature' I realized: hey, at this point, **I should be using templates anyway**.

After some consideration I've come to the conclusion that **Notepad++ shouldn't do this**, to encourage good coding practices.

I'm only embarrassed that it took me so long to realize that it was no longer my editor's job to make my code readable, but mine.

GLHF

Comment: Don't you hate that when non-answers are answers? I do.

Comment: This is an awful answer, and not at all an answer to the question.  He didn't ask what best practice was, he asked for a solution to a problem and this does not provide that.  I have Notepad++ installed at work and at home.  The same PHP file at each location behaves differently: at work it highlights, at home it doesn't, and so "Thankfully, no" is also incorrect.  I know this is old but Stack Overflow is supposed to be helpful, and this answer really, really isn't.

Comment: enter at least 15 characters