# highlight "<?php" ---- "?>" inside "<html>" --- "</html>" in notepad++?

Tags: php, html, highlighting

```
<html>
   This is file is called "example.php".<br>
   <?php print "=== This is printed by a php 'print' statement<br>"; ?>
   This text is after the embedded php.
</html>
```

When either of the html tags, its mate is found, and both are given a distinctive color.
But the php tags don't find their mates, and don't get highlighted.  How can I get that behavior?

Comment: There is an answer to similar question here https://superuser.com/questions/235320/different-language-syntax-highlighting-within-same-file and here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6804134/is-there-anyway-to-have-notepad-highlight-both-php-and-html-at-the-same-time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Save your file in .php extention in notepad ++.
2. If that does not sort the problem download the latest version of notepad++ from [here.](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/)

Here : it works see :) -

[image]

Let me know if anyother issues :)

Comment: Many thanks.  May be the new version, or maybe a setting  that (in my desperation) I did not understand correctly.